# npm install for node server only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

This is probably a very green question, but I've been designing a react app for a while using webpack and installing various packages using npm install.  Every package is for some front end widget such as tabs, or D3, etc.  My question is does this mean I have to make my server a node server if and when I go production?  Could it be a Flask server, or some other random type and still use these node packages?  I know that seems like a stupid question because I'm using node, and they're called node modules, but they're all for the front end and not the back end, so I don't know if they require a node back end or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is does this mean I have to make my server a node server if and when I go production?

Nope.  You can use whatever web server you like.  WebPack is going to bundle everything up as static resources which are deployed to your server in a normal way.

In fact, you probably *shouldn't* be using Node.js for normal static HTTP file serving.  You would have a more performant site by using something like Nginx.

NPM was poorly named, but the naming made more sense at the time it was created.  Web developers can use it as a package manager as well.